# Fate Points, can I have more than 1?

Tags: the-void

I'm playing The Void and rules state that:

> All Characters begin with one Fate Point. Once a Fate Point is spent,
>   you get it back the game session after next. You’ll be without one for
>   one complete session, so be careful.

So... Do I get to have more than 1 point if I don't spend it or the maximum is 1?

Answer (score 2):

No.

If you don't spend it, then you don't trigger the condition "Once a Fate Point is spent…" which is a prerequisite for "you get it back the game session after next".